# How do I prepopulate form fileds in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using apex to create an application that has a database backend.
The application allows the users to search for institutions according to specific criteria, once the criteria are specified, a report is displayed to the user including the institution name and the logo of the institution. The name column is linked to a page that displays the details of a chosen institution.

I want to create a link from the details page that takes the user to the 'Contact US' page which should have some prepopulated form fields like the institution name and email etc. However, I'm not sure how to pass the institution id so that the fields can be prepopulated.

Comment: Pass the institution id through the link to a page item on the contact us page via the link.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your report, have the institution id as a column of type `link` next to name and logo.  Make the `target page` your contact us page and populate the institution id page item with `#INSTITUTION_ID#` (or whatever your institution_id column is called.